# Magento simplexml_load_string() error location

Tags: php, xml, magento

I have a really annoying problem. I was doing some alterations to Magento shop when I ran into simplexml_load_string() error, it is clear to me that this error is caused by some bad XML file, but the very important question to me is which file and where is it located? 
This is the error message I receive, I was never very good at understanding these console type messages, can someone please help me?

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name  in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450

#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/var/www/html/a...', 450, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(450): simplexml_load_string('< ?xml version=...', 'Mage_Core_Model...')
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(275): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->getFileLayoutUpdatesXml('frontend', 'MyTheme', 'Responsive', '1')
#3 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(347): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->fetchFileLayoutUpdates()
#4 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(246): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->fetchPackageLayoutUpdates('default')
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(224): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->merge('default')
#6 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(306): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->load()
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(109): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayoutUpdates()
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'about-magento-d...')
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'about-magento-d...')
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /var/www/html/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's something related with `/var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php` so I would edit that file and I would go to the line 450.

Just before that line write:

```
Mage::log(print_r($filename, true));
```

Make sure  that your logging is enabled and refresh the page. After that, take a look to var/log/system.log. The last xml is probably what you are searching for.

Comment: You saved my life sir, THANK YOU! Turns out Magento added a space just after the opening tag of XML file and that was the problem. With your help I was able to find the faulty file and fix it. Thanks again! :)