# Reoccurring XML error in Magento system.log

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.9

On our Magento store (ver 1.9.01) I recently discovered that our system.log file was 21GB! There seems to be an error regarding a particular line of code which is reoccurring over and over again, here's an example of the errors:

```
2015-09-26T06:06:29+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: ufacturers/resized/A5M-Logo.png&lt;/33&gt;&lt;25&gt;manufacturers/resized/aima-logo_1_.png&lt;/  in /home/pharm1/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2015-09-26T06:06:29+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]:                                                                                ^  in /home/pharm1/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2015-09-26T06:06:29+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: Entity: line 49: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name  in /home/pharm1/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2015-09-26T06:06:29+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: turers/resized/A5M-Logo.png&lt;/33&gt;&lt;25&gt;manufacturers/resized/aima-logo_1_.png&lt;/25&gt;&lt;  in /home/pharm1/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
2015-09-26T06:06:29+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]:                                                                                ^  in /home/pharm1/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
```

Here's the offending piece of code in the config file:

```
    public function loadCache()
{
    if (!$this->validateCacheChecksum()) {
        return false;
    }

    $xmlString = $this->_loadCache($this->getCacheId());
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString, $this->_elementClass);
    if ($xml) {
        $this->_xml = $xml;
        $this->setCacheSaved(true);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

With the line beginning with $xml being the offending line 383.

Please can someone help me get rid of this error? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following just after the simplexml_load_string(..) call:

Mage::log(print_r($file, true));

This will make the log give you a list of all the files loaded at the time the string failed to parse. People have said that the last file on the list is most likely the culprit, but I haven't had much luck with that.

There's similar topics here:
[Magento simplexml_load_string() error location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842275/magento-simplexml-load-string-error-location)