# ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():

Tags: php, magento

ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 48: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name  in /home/productvila/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 451
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():         <<!-- reference name="right">  in /home/productvila/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 451
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():          ^  in /home/productvila/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 451
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/downloadable.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/pagecache.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/persistent.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/weee.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/autosearch.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/vendorplace.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/iwd_all.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/iwd_opc.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/ajaxcartsuper.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/ajaxlogin.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/banner7.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/bestsellerproductslider.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/magentothem_blog.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/brandslider.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/categorytabsliders.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/custommenu.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/featuredproductslider.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/googlesnippet.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/imagerotator.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/lastesttweet.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/layerednavigationajax.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/mostviewedproductslider.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/newproductslider.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/newsletterpopup.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/onsaleslider.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/prozoom.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/quickview.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/relatedslider.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/testimonial.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/themeoptions.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/upsellslider.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/ma_mutoshop/ma_mutoshop3/layout/vmegamenu.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7): /home/productvila/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/paytm.xml
2017-05-30T06:44:15+00:00 DEBUG (7):

Comment: Add your question, only error trace is not enough for understanding it.

Comment: After theme change I got these error in error log please help me .what should I do for same..

Comment: I think this question is duplicate, check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842275/magento-simplexml-load-string-error-location

Comment: I followed this question sir after add Mage::log(print_r($filename, true)); this line in update.php I got the list of xml files but what next we need to do  please help me.I am unbale to catch the xml errors.

Comment: Please show your log result

Comment: Thanks Sir related to this error I have resolved I am confused to which file should I check because there were a list of xml files then I check the last file there were mistake in xml file not commented properly!!

Comment: This is my first expereince on stckoverflow and I feel it really helpfull.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is occurring due to miss match of your xml tag for example..

in you theme

```
<tag>
  <child></child>
</tagg>
```

so here closing tag miss match the opening tag.
go to your theme layout and search for any miss match tag

Comment: Yes sir thanks there were error on my xml file.I resolved it thanks a lot sir

Comment: Pleasure you can like my answer if it was helpful.